# Unix script to search a directory from a reference file

Tags: unix, grep, redhat

I have a reference csv file which have Column1,Column2. I need the list of files names in the directory which has the value in **column1 and column2 in the same record(line)**. Check this recursively for all the reference data in the csv file and the output should be something like... "column1,column2,filename"...

**The files can also be .dat files and .gz zip files**. Please help me with a unix script for this. Version Red Hat 6.9.

```
**Csv Reference File:**  
Column1,Column2  
Record1Col1,Record1Col2  
Record2Col1,Record2Col2  
Record3Col1,Record3Col2  
Record4Col1,Record4Col2  
Record5Col1,Record5Col2  

**Output:**  
Record1Col1,Record1Col2,txt1.dat  
Record1Col1,Record1Col2,txt2.dat  
Record1Col1,Record1Col2,txtzip1.gz  
Record2Col1,Record2Col2,txt2.dat  
Record2Col1,Record2Col2,txtzip5.gz  
Record4Col1,Record4Col2,txtzip7.gz  

sample data file...  
**txt1.dat:**  
Xyz|somevalue|Record1Col1|somevalue|somevalue|123|Record1Col2|xyz|  
Abc|somevalue|somevalue|somevalue|xyz|  
Record2Col1|somevalue|Somevalue|123|somevalue|
```

Comment: It's not clear enough what you request, show the sample csv file and expected output.

Comment: added as per request

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in the description that requires recursion.  Perhaps you are using that word incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `awk` to do this,

```
$ cat awk-script 
NR==FNR{                      # in reference.csv
  a[FNR]=$1;b[FNR]=$2;        # record the first field into a[FNR], and second into b[FNR]
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){         # for other files,
    if(($0 ~ a[i]) && ($0 ~ b[i]))   # search if each line contained a[i] && b[i]
      print a[i],b[i],FILENAME       # print it if yes
  }
}

$ awk -F'[, ]' -v OFS="," -f awk-script reference.csv *[^csv]
Record1Col1,Record1Col2,txt1.dat
Record1Col1,Record1Col2,txt2.dat
```

Explanation,

- Set the field separator as `[, ]`, since there are some records appends with spaces in your post. And also set the output separator `OFS=","` for your request output.
- Note that I force the processed file order for `awk` as `reference.csv *[^csv]`. So `awk` would parse reference.csv firstly and then other non-csv file. The order cannot be changed since we need to record the value in reference.csv first, then we can look them into other files.
- For `awk-script`, you may see the appended comments for more detailed.

Let me know if this helps you.